# "firebase deploy --only functions" issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I’m now developing the app by dart and want to use functions, so I try to use below command and deploy

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

the below sentences are result of this command

```
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
Error: double-loading config "/Users/username/.cache/firebase/runtime/npmrc" as "global", previously loaded as "user"
    at Config.#loadObject (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:571:13)
    at /snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:617:31
    at async Config.#loadFile (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:616:5)
    at async Config.load (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:287:5)
    at async Npm.#load (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:195:5)
    at async /snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:40:5

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

To resolve them, I tried

- update FCL command
- down grade npm
- make dependencies clear
- move “.npmrc” file and so command
  however I can’t deploy.
  There’s not so many refelences on web, so please help me …

Comment: Firebase Cloud Functions is really easy to start over because all you really have is a single source code file called `index`. Therefore, I'd recommend creating a brand new project in a new folder using the installation steps in the documentation and then simply copying and pasting the old index file into this new project. If that doesn't resolve the issue then I'd consider reinstalling frameworks and programs.